# ldapsearch does not return users with special chars (e.g. user.name) on AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, filtering, wildcard

I want to search for users with descriptions in AD which on Windows Powershell can be done with the PowerView function `Get-DomainUser`:

```
Get-DomainUser -v * | Select-Object samaccountname,description | Where-Object {$_.Description -ne $null}

VERBOSE: [Get-DomainSearcher] search base: LDAP://LAB-DC01.DOMAIN.LOCAL/DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL
VERBOSE: [Get-DomainUser] filter string: (&(samAccountType=805306368)(|(samAccountName=*)))

samaccountname description
-------------- -----------
administrator  Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
jdoe           .......................
user.name      FOOBAR
```

Now I want to get that list on a Linux machine with ldapsearch. Using the search filter from Get-DomainUser I tested the following ldapsearch command line which indeed lists the accounts and I can grep for descriptions:

```
ldapsearch -h 172.12.0.1 -D 'domain\user' -w 'pass' -b "DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" "(&(samAccountType=805306368)(|(samAccountName=*)))"
```

However, I noticed that this search does not return the account `user.name`. Even if I completely remove the name filter using only `"(samAccountType=805306368)"` it is not returned.

Only if I explicitly search the pattern with `"(&(samAccountType=805306368)(|(samAccountName=*.*)))"` it returns this (and only this) account.

Why is this account not returned? Is there a more "general" wildcard? There's also a "user-name" which I must filter with `*-*`.

Comment: Try Just (samAccountType=805306368)

Logon names (i.e. samAccountAName) cannot contain certain " / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < > Logon names can contain all other special characters, including spaces, periods, dashes, and underscores. 
But "Best Practices" use NOThiNG but letters, numbers and "-". 
Several third-party products and integrations will fail on these entries if you do.

Comment: Removing certain characters from user isn't always a possibility... You can probably start by simplifying your filter to `(&(samAccountType=805306368)(samAccountName=*))`. Then I would do the inverse search to see how ldapsearch interprets `user.name`. What do you get searching for `(description=FOOBAR*)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh crap. In fact, it has nothing to do with the search filter and special chars at all. The returned result is just simply to big...

I traced the ldap connection from `Get-DomainUser` with wireshark and I noticed the ldap result is returned paginated - but I still thought nothing of it.

Before `ldapsearch` I actually tried the tool `crackmapexec` to get the user description but it didn't work. So now I tried it again and had a closer look at the error message: `LDAPSearchError: Error in searchRequest -> 'sizeLimitExceeded'`...

And in fact, after I instructed ldapsearch to use pagination with the parameter `-E pr=2147483647/noprompt` the user in question is also returned with my search filter. It really was just a coincident that this user was not in the partial result.